# PHP SOAP Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2

Tags: php, web-services, soap, webserver

Well, I've been searching how to fix the bug and nothing seems to work, these are a few of solutions I've tried:

- Reduce the content in soap response
- Setting content-length header in Soap Server
- Less exposed web service methods

I can load my wsdl in the browser and I get a well-formed XML response, I can make requests and it works !...but sometimes I still getting the same error "Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2".

Any other solution?

Comment: you "cant load my wsdl in the browser" ??? Strange. It should be able to  open.

Comment: sorry 'can load my wsdl in the browser'

Comment: catch errors and put it in the log. then inspect it.

Comment: this is the only mistake: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://api/v2/wsdl/Invoices.wsdl' : Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2

Comment: that's weird, sometimes works..sometimes crash and kick my b**ls.

Comment: look to your server log files to see why is your api/v2/wsdl/Invoices.wsdl file is inaccessible

Comment: access log: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2011:03:51:16 -0500] "POST /v2/WSInvoices.php HTTP/1.1" 200 25565 ...and my error log is empty.

Comment: Seeing similar "premature end of data" error; came across [this old post](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49226) about missing content header in chunked response maybe breaking PHP 5.3.  Also maybe [this link](http://51banshi.net/questions/1953174/magento-soap-error-premature-end-of-data-in-tag-definitions-line-2) has other info.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch error and write XML data to log file and inspect your "definifions" tag for some errors

Comment: "write XML data to log file" > How ??